# What is the best way to convert 1/8" cable to dual 1/4" input monitors

Tags: cable, conversion, monitors, studio

I recently bought a pair of JBL LSR305 studio monitors:
https://www.sweetwater.com/store/detail/LSR305--jbl-lsr305-5-inch-powered-studio-monitor

They sound great, but they only have a 1/4" cable input on the back. I'm mostly using my laptop and iPhone as an audio source so I bought this 1/8" to 1/4" Y cable:
[https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B00ZKM3S4S/ref=oh_aui_detailpage_o01_s00?ie=UTF8&th=1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00ZKM3S4S)

What I didn't realize is that this cable only splits a few inches before the 1/4" cable begins, meaning the speakers can't really be separated.

What's the best way to extend the range of the input so I can have these speakers sit on opposite sides of a desk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution would be a pair of unbalanced (TS) 1/4" cables of a length which permits desired speaker separation, and a pair of unbalanced 1/4" barrel adapters. (female-female).

Connection should be pretty self-explanatory.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Why unbalanced instead of balanced, just out of curiosity? And wouldn't it be easier just to get a male-female 1/4" cord like this: https://www.amazon.com/InstallerParts-Female-Audio-Extension-Cable/dp/B008I926RK?ref_=fsclp_pl_dp_8

Comment: Unbalanced because your source is unbalanced. And sure,  that cable you linked would work, too. I suppose the reason I would prefer the solution I suggested above is that for future flexibility I would rather have standard cables and adapters instead of cables that are permanently configured as female-to-male cables.

Comment: You are welcome. You can accept and/or upvote the answer if you feel that it was helpful.